# How to get repeating element in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get the repeating "Author" element in the following XML structure against each product. How will i do it? I am using the following online tool for testing
http://xslttest.appspot.com/

**XML**

```
<OrderDocument>
  <OrderProduct>
    <Product>
      <ProductDescription>ProductDescription</ProductDescription>
      <Author>Author</Author>
      <Author>Author</Author>
    </Product>
   </OrderProduct>  
   <OrderProduct>
    <Product>
      <ProductDescription>ProductDescription</ProductDescription>
      <Author>Author</Author>
      <Author>Author</Author>
    </Product>
   </OrderProduct>  
   <OrderProduct>
    <Product>
      <ProductDescription>ProductDescription</ProductDescription>
      <Author>Author</Author>
      <Author>Author</Author>
    </Product>
   </OrderProduct>      
</OrderDocument>
```

**XSLT File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="//OrderDocument">


   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output Required:**

```
<Message>
 <Product>
           <Author>Author</Author>
          <Author>Author</Author>
 </Product>
  <Product>
           <Author>Author</Author>
          <Author>Author</Author>
 </Product>
</Message>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [xsl to only copy some elements recursively and remove some of the descendants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282741/xsl-to-only-copy-some-elements-recursively-and-remove-some-of-the-descendants)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a transformation where you are not changing the entire XML document, you usually start off with the [XSLT identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you only need to write templates for the nodes you do wish to transform. Looking at your input and expected output, there are three things you need to do

Rename the `OrderDocument` element to `Message`
Remove the `OrderProduct` element, but keep processing its children
Remove the `ProductDescription` element entirely

Each of these can be achieve by a separate template. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Rename OrderDocument to Message -->
    <xsl:template match="OrderDocument">
        <Message>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove OrderProduct, but keep processing its children -->
    <xsl:template match="OrderProduct">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove ProductDescription entirely -->
    <xsl:template match="ProductDescription" />

    <!-- Identity Template for everything else -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your very descriptive answer. But i was hoping to achieve that with the help of any loop structure. Like For each etc. Is it possible by that??

Comment: @omerkhalid, the approach taken by Tim  in his stylesheet (using the identity transformation template and additional template that override its behaviour) is the proper one for XSLT for your problem and many others, try to learn from it, don't try to solve that with `for-each`.

Comment: I totally understands it. But actually this part is just a subset of my whole document. As great this solution is I cannot apply the above mentioned solution in my case. I need a simple solution that i can apply inside one tag. I cannot share my complete document because of confidentiality issues.

Comment: If your original document has confidential data, then you should be able to replace such data with random data. We don't need to see the original, but the XML that you do post does need to representative of the original. That way you will get a more accurate answer. There is nothing wrong with using xsl:for-each in XSLT, but with the question as the moment, there is no need to. Thank you.

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion but please understand my position.  My document structure is different. I need this solution with for each or any kind of loop in one tag. It would be your great curtsey to me if you can please guide me that how to solve the above mentioned problem with for each.  So far i have achieved this.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <!-- Rename OrderDocument to Message -->
    <xsl:template match="OrderDocument">
        <Message>
            
 <xsl:for-each select="Product">
  <AuthorO>      
<xsl:value-of select="Product/Author" />
</AuthorO>
</xsl:for-each> 
        </Message>

Comment: You should edit your question with the XSLT you have tried with the `xsl:for-each` as it is hard to read code in comments. You should also explain in your question, rather than in just comments, why doing it this way is important. If you do that, then I should be able to amend my answer to help. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the following xslt and it worked. But thanks anyways for your help.<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0"><xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//OrderDocument">
     <Message>
     <xsl:for-each select="OrderProduct/Product ">
         <Product>
         <xsl:for-each select="Author ">
             <Author><xsl:value-of select="."/></Author>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </Product>
</xsl:for-each>
</Message>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>